# python pandas index is_unique not working

Tags: python, pandas, unique, indexing

I'm new to python so please call me on not including relevant information.

I've installed python, ipython, and am using the notebook on an Ubuntu installation in a VM.

I'm working through examples laid out in Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis.  After the following import statements:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
```

I defined a dataframe with:

```
series1 = Series(range(5), index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'])
```

And subsequently wanted to test the indexes uniqueness with:

```
series1.index.is_unique
```

And get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/username/<ipython-input-64-e42615bb2da2> in <module>()
----> 1 series1.index.is_unique
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'is_unique'
```

The book indicates this attribute exists.  Other stackoverflow questions and answers reference this attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

After being asked what version of pandas I was using, I checked and it was 0.7.0
Upgrading with

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Got me where I needed to be.

Comment: What `pandas.__version__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you are using an updated version, no issues here with `0.11.0`:

```
>>> from pandas import Series, DataFrame
>>> s = Series(range(5), index=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'])
>>> s.index.is_unique
False
```

Either download the most recent version from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas#downloads), or upgrade from command line:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

For this snippet there's no need to `import pandas as pd` on the second line, so I've removed it.

Comment: Thanks beargle.  I was using 0.7.0.  Upgraded and was fine.